# How to find $R_Y(\tau)$ if $Y(t)=X(t)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0t+\theta)$ where $\theta \sim \text{unif}[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

Suppose $X(t)$ is wide-sense stationary (WSS) process.

> How to find $R_Y(\tau)$ if $Y(t)=X(t)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0t+\theta)$ where $\theta \sim \text{unif}[-\pi,\pi]$.

The answer is:

> $R_Y(\tau)=\frac{1}{2} R_X(\tau)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0 \tau)$

My problem is:

$R_Y(\tau)=E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)]=E[X(t)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0t+\theta)\ \ X(t+\tau)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0(t+\tau)\theta)]$

What is the expected value for?  $E = E_{\theta}$?

If yes, then $X(t)$ and $X(t+\tau)$ can be pulled out of the $E$, i.e.
$X(t)X(t+\tau)E[\text{cos}(2\pi f_0t+\theta)\ \ \text{cos}(2\pi f_0(t+\tau)\theta)]$, then I cannot get $R_X(\tau)$.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: I guess you need  an assumption that the related variables are uncorrelated. If this holds then $E(Y(t)Y(t+\tau))=E(X(t)X(t+\tau))E(\cos(2\pi f_0t+\theta)\cos(2\pi f_0(t+\tau)\theta))$.

Comment: Sould we  add this assumption?  My reason is $\text{cos}(2\pi f_0 t+\theta)$ has no element about $X(t)$. So they could be uncorrelated.

Comment: Well, if $X(t)$, $\theta$ are independent the related functions in the average  operator are uncorrelated (the reverse does not hold in general). But if you want to be strict you have to precisely state this fact.

Answer (score 0):

$R_Y(\tau)=E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)]=E[X(t)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0t+\theta)\ \ X(t+\tau)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0(t+\tau)\theta)]$
$R_Y(\tau)=E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)]=E[X(t)X(t+\tau)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0t+\theta)\ \ \text{cos}(2\pi f_0(t+\tau)\theta)]$

using $cosAcosB$ identity we get
$R_Y(\tau)=E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)]=E[X(t)X(t+\tau)\text{cos}(2\pi f_0t+\theta+\pi f_0\tau)\ \ \text{cos}(2\pi f_0\tau))]$

$R_Y(\tau)=E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)]=E[X(t)X(t+\tau)\text(1)\ \ \text{cos}(2\pi f_0\tau))]$

as $cos(2\pi(any term)))=1$

$R_Y(\tau)=E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)]=R\_x(\tau) \ \text{cos}(2\pi f_0\tau))]$